# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for my UITextField

Tags: json, swift, null, optional-values

I'm having trouble passing the JSON values (I'm reading successfully) into my `textfield` on the next `viewcontroller` because of this unwrapping error, stating my text field is `nil`.

I'm very stuck. Here's my class that reads the JSON:

```
class DoOAuth
{
func doOAuthFitbit() -> String{
    var name = ""
    let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey:            "eabf603efe9e45168d057b60b03f8e94",
        consumerSecret:         "46b4dfa8c9d59666769e03f887d531a8",
        requestTokenUrl:        "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token",
        authorizeUrl:           "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?display=touch",
        accessTokenUrl:         "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token")

    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "fitbit://oauth")!,
        success:{
            credential, response in

            let vc: ViewController = ViewController()


            let user: OAuthSwiftClient = OAuthSwiftClient(consumerKey: oauthswift.consumer_key, consumerSecret: oauthswift.consumer_secret, accessToken: credential.oauth_token, accessTokenSecret: credential.oauth_token_secret)

            let object:[String : AnyObject] = ["oauth_token": credential.oauth_token, "oauth_token_secret" : credential.oauth_token_secret]

            user.get("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json", parameters: object,
                success: {

                    (data: NSData, response: NSHTTPURLResponse) -> Void in
                    let jsonValues = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
                    println(jsonValues)

                    /*public var dictionary: [Swift.String: JSON]?
                    {
                        switch self
                        {
                        case .Dictionary(let d):
                            var jsonObject: [Swift.String: JSON] = [:]
                            for(k,v) in d
                            {
                                jsonObject[k] = JSON.wrap(v)
                            }
                            return jsonObject
                        default:
                            return nil
                        }
                    }*/

                    for(key, subJson) in jsonValues
                    {
                        if let nm = subJson["fullName"].string
                        {
                            println("\(nm)")

                            name = nm
                        }
                    }

                    /*for(index: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonValues
                    {
                        let name = subJson.dictionary?["fullName"]?.string

                        println("\(name!)")
                        //vc.nm.text = name!
                        main.acceptJson(name!)

                    }*/
                },
                failure: {
                    (error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
                    println("error")
            })
        },
        failure: {
            (error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
    })
    return name
}
```

}

I call a function that is supposed to receive the JSON strings (`acceptJson`) located in the next view controller:

```
class mainMenu: UIViewController
{
var oauthfitbit: DoOAuth = DoOAuth()
var name = ""

//let vc: ViewController = ViewController()

@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!{
    didSet{
        nameField.text = name
    }
}



 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
 {
        //name = oauthfitbit.doOAuthFitbit()
        //self.nameField.text = "Working"
        //self.nameField.text = name
 }

func acceptJson(info: String!)
{
    println("\(info)")
    self.nameField.text = info
    //name = info

}

}
```

I get the excepting thrown on the setting `nameField.text` line stating `nameField` is `nil`. How do I get the `textfield` to store the JSON string?
And here's the initial View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var nm: UITextField!
//let main: mainMenu = mainMenu()

var name = ""
@IBAction func connectPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    var oauthFitbit: DoOAuth = DoOAuth()
    name = oauthFitbit.doOAuthFitbit()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "loginSuccess")
    {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! mainMenu
        controller.name = name
        //vc.nameField.text = "Hello"

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you segueing to the second view controller (i.e. mainMenu)?

Comment: yup, self.performseguewithidentifier is the very first thing called in the IBAction button, then the function that loads the jsonValues is called.  Then in that function I call "acceptJson" to pass what I just loaded

Comment: You shouldn't segue (i.e. call `performSegueWithIdentifier`) until **after** you have gotten the data you need to pass to the second view controller.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to this, I kind of see what you mean, just wanted to make sure I was applying it right, so I have the two view controllers and the class that reads the jsonvalues (called in the first view controller) and then the performseguewithidentifier is called;  I added your suggestion, but to no avail; it's probably something stupid on my part.  I edited the post to include everything

Comment: Change nameField.text = vc.text to nameField.text = name in didSet in your mainMenu class

Comment: You're segueing from ViewController to mainMenu, aren't you? Why do you have a vc instance variable in mainMenu? It doesn't look like it's doing anything.

Comment: ok commented that out and yup I'm segueing from ViewController to mainMenu. I changed what you said and the textfield is still blank. No more errors though!  Could the problem be with the class reading the jsonValues?

Comment: In the for loop, change vc.name = nm to name = nm. Again, I don't know what that vc variable is doing. Then make sure the for loop is run before segueing.

Comment: Is there another way I can reach you?  Just didn't want to make this a run-on.  I have the vc variable so that I can access the instance variable I declared in the ViewController class (initial).  That for loop code is located in a class of it's own so I can't just use "name" or I get the "unresolved identifier"

Comment: Ahh, I see. Usually you would just create an instance of the class that has the `doOAuthFitbit()` method in the first view controller and call `doOAuthFitbit()` on that instance. I would modify `doOAuthFitbit()` so that it returns the data you need to your first view controller (looks like it would return a string). I'll update my answer...

Comment: ***Updated**** Ok, I'm going to update my post.  I was actually trying that solution too, the text field is still showing up blank.  It looks like the segue is being called before the function for some reason or is it because of the var name = "" i have in mainMenu setting it back to a blank string

Comment: I know the problem; the problem is that `name` is being set in a closure. So, the method is returning a string before the completion handler is called. The only way I can think of fixing this problem is making `name` an instance variable (instead of local variable) in `DoOAuth`, and sending out an `NSNotification` in a `didSet` property observer on `name`. Then `ViewController` can sign up to "listen for" that notification and call `performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: nil)` when it receives that notification.

Answer (score 1):

How did you create your textfield? Was it through Interface Builder? There have been plenty of times when I've run into these type of problems when using Interface Builder and IBOutlets.

The first step is to make sure your text field is connected to your view controller from the .xib file correctly. Delete the connection and reconnect by control (command?) dragging from IB to your view controller code.

If you're not using IB and still having problems, post the code where you create the textfield. You have to set your view controller as the text field delegate if you're creating it programmatically, I believe. It's been awhile since I've done it that way.

Let us know!

Comment: Yea, through interface builder and  I connected it by control dragging to the view controller from the storyboard, I just deleted and reconnected it and it didn't work

Comment: Ok. Hmmm. So I'm not sure where the problem could be then. Are you sure the nil is your text field? Could it be your info as String! parameter? Put a breakpoint at the line where you call acceptJson(string) and a point on println("\(info)").

Run the project and check in the debugging window which of these is nil. Get back to us and we can go from there.

Comment: Yup it's the textfield coming up as nil, I put those print statements to make sure i was getting the Json data and it is printing it just fine subJson["fullName"] is printing "Drew McCalla" and again in that print statement in my function.  I do have my initial view controller with a button that calls the function with the jsonValues and for loop, then below that I have a "self.performseguewithidentifier" to move to the next view controller where i encounter the error.  Should I post the rest?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the new view controller the value of `nm` is in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! mainMenu
    controller.name = name
  }
}
```

So, to get this to work, you will need to add a `name` instance variable (`var name = ""`) to your first view controller, and change `main.acceptJson(nm)` to `name = nm`.

Once `name` is set in your first view controller, you can segue to the second view controller.

In the second view controller, you can change your text field outlet to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField! {
  didSet {
    nameField.text = name
  }
}
```

The `didSet` is a **property observer**. You can't set the `nameField` text field directly from the first view controller's `prepareForSegue` because the text field isn't set up yet when `prepareForSegue` is called in the first view controller. That's why you're storing it in an instance variable. Then, because of the `didSet`, your text field's text property will be set as soon as it comes into existence.

**UPDATE:**

The following is in a class of its own. Let's call that class `DoOAuth` (looks like that's what you called it):

```
class DoOAuth {

func doOAuthFitbit() -> String { // Now it's returning a string

    var name = "" // Create local variable to return

    let oauthswift = OAuth1Swift(
        consumerKey:            "eabf603efe9e45168d057b60b03f8e94",
        consumerSecret:         "46b4dfa8c9d59666769e03f887d531a8",
        requestTokenUrl:        "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token",
        authorizeUrl:           "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?display=touch",
        accessTokenUrl:         "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token")

    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "fitbit://oauth")!,
        success:{
            credential, response in

            //let vc: ViewController = ViewController() // Get rid of this

            let user: OAuthSwiftClient = OAuthSwiftClient(consumerKey: oauthswift.consumer_key, consumerSecret: oauthswift.consumer_secret, accessToken: credential.oauth_token, accessTokenSecret: credential.oauth_token_secret)

            let object:[String : AnyObject] = ["oauth_token": credential.oauth_token, "oauth_token_secret" : credential.oauth_token_secret]

            user.get("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json", parameters: object,
                success: {

                    (data: NSData, response: NSHTTPURLResponse) -> Void in
                    let jsonValues = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
                    println(jsonValues)

                    /*public var dictionary: [Swift.String: JSON]?
                    {
                        switch self
                        {
                        case .Dictionary(let d):
                            var jsonObject: [Swift.String: JSON] = [:]
                            for(k,v) in d
                            {
                                jsonObject[k] = JSON.wrap(v)
                            }
                            return jsonObject
                        default:
                            return nil
                        }
                    }*/

                    for(key, subJson) in jsonValues
                    {
                        if let nm = subJson["fullName"].string
                        {
                            println("\(nm)")

                            name = nm // Store 'nm' in local variable declared above
                        }
                    }
        }
        return name
    } // end doOAuthFitbit()

} // end class
```

Now change your `connectPressed()` method in ViewController to this:

```
@IBAction func connectPressed(sender: UIButton)
{
    var oauthFitbit: DoOAuth = DoOAuth()
    name = oauthFitbit.doOAuthFitbit() // doOAuthFitbit() now returns a String
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSuccess", sender: nil)
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: @DrewMcCalla The most important thing is that the instance variable `name` in the first view controller is set **before** initiating the segue.